# Efficient Java Collection to analyse the inputs from CSV file with millions of records

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Lets say I have  a csv file with  stock exchange information  in following format: timestamp, name , price, qty, account, buy/sell .
This file may have millions of records and represents the trading activity for the day.
The file is not sorted and I  need to choose the most optimal Java collection for holding this data in order to provide analytics efficiently.

Analytics Eg :
1)Most sold stock
2) Account with max transactions
3) Highest quantity of stock bought in a time range.
4) Top K people with highest transactions.

Basically I will need to sort this list many times based on  different fields.

So after a little bit of search I found that a Tree based collection is best for this use case . Like a TreeMap . Is there any other collection which would be better ?

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet will be efficient if you want sorted by one parameter.
You can

1. Create a class like:

```java
    public class Record {
        Calendar timeStamp;
        String name;
        double price;
        //...
    }
```

2. Create comparators for each task
3. Create a LinkedList (or other Collection)

```java
    List <Record> records=new LinkedList();
```

4. Use your comparators

```java
    records.sort(yourComparator1);
    records.sort(yourComparator2);
    records.sort(yourComparator3);
```